# 5+ Intermediate SQL Tables to Arrive at Desired Table, Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am generating reports on electoral data that group voters into their age groups, and then assign those age groups a quartile, before finally returning the table of age groups and quartiles.

By the time I arrive at the table with the schema and data that I want, I have created 7 intermediate tables that might as well be deleted at this point.

My question is, is it plausible that so many intermediate tables are necessary?  Or this a sign that I am "doing it wrong?"

Technical Specifics:

Postgres 9.4

I am chaining tables, starting with the raw database tables and successively transforming the table closer to what I want.  For instance, I do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE gm.race_code_and_turnout_count AS
SELECT race_code, count(*)
FROM gm.active_dem_voters_34th_house_in_2012_primary
GROUP BY race_code
```

And then I do

```
CREATE TABLE gm.race_code_and_percent_of_total_turnout AS
SELECT race_code, count, round((count::numeric/11362)*100,2) AS   percent_of_total_turnout
FROM gm.race_code_and_turnout_count
```

And that first table goes off in a second branch:

```
CREATE TABLE gm.race_code_and_turnout_percentage AS
SELECT t1.race_code, round((t1.count::numeric / t2.count)*100,2) as turnout_percentage
FROM gm.race_code_and_turnout_count AS t1
JOIN gm.race_code_and_total_count AS t2
ON t1.race_code = t2.race_code
```

So each table is building on the one before it.

Comment: Why would you need to _create_ tables just to run a report? Please show us your code and tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: If it performs well and results in the right output, I see nothing wrong with it. Those intermediate tables you create, you use temporary tables for those?

Comment: The first two queries can easily be combined into one query (without and performance impact). The second table does not seem to be used in the final query. @tt: if those intermediate tables are not indexed, that this will most probably perform worse than simply using common table expressions because the overhead of writing permanent tables is much higher than spilling derived tables to disk.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, I gave my comment when the OP had no queries edited into his question. It was more of a general statement. If it works and does so in reasonable time I see no problem with intermediate tables. However I would use temporary tables in situations like this (properly indexed of course). Of course things can always be optimized as your rightfully point out =).

Comment: For starters, I'd start from the back and move forward (last temp table first) and replace it with a `with` clause and benchmark performance.  Depending on your server specs/settings and the volume of data, you may find you can run the entire thing in memory faster than the additional overhead of creating tables on the fly.  Also, this may be a good use case for a materialized view.  Without some idea of your data volumes in each table, however, it's difficult to say.  Can you show all intermediate tables and give estimates of # of rows in each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While temporary tables are used a lot in SQL Server (mainly to overcome the peculiar locking behaviour that it has) it is far less common in Postgres (and your example uses *regular* tables, not temporary tables).

Usually the overhead of creating a new table is higher than letting the system store intermediate on disk.

From my experience, creating intermediate tables usually only helps if:

1. you have a **lot** of data that is aggregated and can't be aggregated in memory
2. the aggregation drastically reduces the data volume to be processed so that the next step (or one of the next steps) can handle the data in memory
3. you can efficiently index the intermediate tables so that the next step can make use of those indexes to improve performance.
4. you re-use a pre-computed result several times in different steps

The above list is not completely and using this approach can also be beneficial if only some of these conditions are true.

**If** you keep creating those tables create them at least as `temporary` or `unlogged` tables to minimized the IO overhead that comes with writing that data and thus keep as much data in memory as possible.

However I would always start with a single query instead of maintaining many different tables (that all need to be changed if you have to change the structure of the report).

For example your first two queries from your question can easily be combined into a single query with no performance loss:

```
SELECT race_code, 
       count(*) as cnt,
       round((count(*)::numeric/11362)*100,2) AS percent_of_total_turnout
FROM gm.active_dem_voters_34th_house_in_2012_primary
GROUP BY race_code;
```

This is going to be faster than writing the data twice to disk (including all transactional overhead).

If you stack your queries using common table expressions Postgres will automatically store the data on disk if it gets too big, if not it will process it in-memory. When manually creating the tables you *force* Postgres to write everything to disk.

So you might want to try something like this:

```
with race_code_and_turnout_count as (
  SELECT race_code, 
         count(*) as cnt,
         round((count(*)::numeric/11362)*100,2) AS percent_of_total_turnout
  FROM gm.active_dem_voters_34th_house_in_2012_primary
  GROUP BY race_code
), race_code_and_total_count as (
   select ....
   from ....
), race_code_and_turnout_percentage as (
  SELECT t1.race_code, 
         round((t1.count::numeric / t2.count)*100,2) as turnout_percentage
  FROM ace_code_and_turnout_count AS t1
    JOIN race_code_and_total_count AS t2 
      ON t1.race_code = t2.race_code
)
select *
from ....;
```

and see how that performs.

If you don't re-use the intermediate steps more than once, writing them as a derived table instead of a CTE might be faster in Postgres due to the way the optimizer works, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.race_code, 
       round((t1.count::numeric / t2.count)*100,2) as turnout_percentage
FROM (
  SELECT race_code, 
         count(*) as cnt,
         round((count(*)::numeric/11362)*100,2) AS percent_of_total_turnout
  FROM gm.active_dem_voters_34th_house_in_2012_primary
  GROUP BY race_code
) AS t1
  JOIN race_code_and_total_count AS t2 
    ON t1.race_code = t2.race_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If it performs well and results in the right output, I see nothing wrong with it. I do however suggest to use (local) temporary tables if you need intermediate tables.

Your series of queries can always be optimized to use fewer intermediate steps. Do that if you feel your reports start performing poorly.

Comment: Btw I use the term local temporary tables from a MS SQL Server background. I don't know about Postgresql but I'm assuming it has a similar concept. GL.